# SQL JSON_VALUE query but without path names?

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, open-json, json-value

I have json data that I am trying to import in to a SQL Server database but it doesnt have path names to reference - how do I go by indentifying the different elements here:

Sample json: https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/binance/btcusdt/ohlc?periods=3600

This outputs in the following format but without the names:

```
[
  CloseTime,
  OpenPrice,
  HighPrice,
  LowPrice,
  ClosePrice,
  Volume,
  QuoteVolume
]
```

```
[
    1474736400,
    8744,
    8756.1,
    8710,
    8753.5,
    91.58314308,
    799449.488966417
],
```

Following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

But not sure what to put in here: JSON_VALUE ( expression , path ) as the path bit - any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, you can't use the JSON operations to query something that isn't valid. The "sample" JSON you link to, however, *is* valid JSON, and isn't what you have in your question.

Comment: what I have in my question is a copy from the documentation related to that sample; https://docs.cryptowat.ch/rest-api/markets/ohlc. If its not valid json then what is it? any easy way you might know of, or function that would help me get it in to a SQL server db?

Comment: It's an array, delimited by commas. So you could split the data if you treat it as like a CSV.

Comment: I want to create a job that proceses that data and continually imports so need to process it all in SQL server. Was using this: https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer/blob/master/README.md but it falls over as far as I can see without being able to define the individual elements

Comment: I feel like what you're saying here is this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: yes - i know what I need as an output, have not much of a clue what to do to describe this properly or what to look for to sort this, so was hoping for some guidance on here. appreciate your help though

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a bunch of arrays representing rows.  A query like this should do it:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '
{"result":{"3600":[[1606705200,18482.31,18550,18435.81,18506.87,2470.427799,45664903.49372367],[1606708800,18506.87,18593.81, ...
'

select dateadd(second,cast(json_value([value],'$[0]') as bigint),'19700101') CloseTime,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[1]') as float) OpenPrice,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[2]') as float) HighPrice,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[3]') as float) LowPrice,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[4]') as float) ClosePrice,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[5]') as float) Volume,
       cast(json_value([value],'$[6]') as float) QuoteVolume

from openjson(@json,'$.result."3600"')
```

which outputs

```
CloseTime               OpenPrice              HighPrice              LowPrice               ClosePrice             Volume                 QuoteVolume
----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
2020-11-30 03:00:00.000 18482.31               18550                  18435.81               18506.87               2470.427799            45664903.4937237
2020-11-30 04:00:00.000 18506.87               18593.81               18431.26               18579.5                2283.371404            42288794.16279
2020-11-30 05:00:00.000 18579.67               18619.79               18450                  18523.79               2119.718173            39247661.0930612
2020-11-30 06:00:00.000 18523.79               18627.29               18477.62               18520.47               1835.535407            34068066.5616724
2020-11-30 08:00:00.000 18520.27               18677                  18512.9                18623                  3499.555499            65178082.9264658
2020-11-30 09:00:00.000 18623.05               18625                  18375.55               18462.31               4220.609403            77972731.2494644
2020-11-30 10:00:00.000 18462.7                18510                  18326.03               18478.54               3054.085606            56248649.2319086
2020-11-30 11:00:00.000 18478.54               18589                  18446.5                18503.06               2240.917883            41516090.5672204
2020-11-30 12:00:00.000 18503.11               18655                  18503.11               18600.95               3413.482688            63562162.7584654
2020-11-30 13:00:00.000 18600.94               18840                  18600.94               18837.16               4675.208754            87625034.6027069
2020-11-30 14:00:00.000 18835.97               19210                  18788.11               19151.49               9286.987366            176378855.887698
2020-11-30 15:00:00.000 19151.49               19782.1                19135                  19480.8                15792.38031            307214715.045745
```

Comment: appreciated - will give this a go!

Comment: yes this worked perfectly, even fixed the unix time for me - thank you!